# What does the padlock mean in the QGIS project icon?

Tags: qgis, icon, qgz

What does the lock mean in the .qgz file icon?

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to QGIS but related to your file system windows manager. What is your OS? If Windows, https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17117/remove-the-lock-icon-from-a-folder-in-windows-7/

Comment: @ThomasG77 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but often it means a file is restricted to only certain users. What I found in a few google searches backs this up.